# Un son bizarre se produit en prononçant des mots comme "conclure"/"concurrence"

Tags: prononciation

Chaque fois que je prononce ces mots (qui commencent par "conc"), je produit un son bizarre avec ma bouche. On dirait une goutte. Avez-vous entendu parler de ce problème auparavant? Écoutez le lien ci-dessous. Le son est plus distinct pour moi, mais vous pouvez quand même l'entendre.

https://www.speakpipe.com/voice-recorder/msg/u2nmwlmdww33fbvq

Je me demande si j'ai un mauvais prononciation? Ou que puis-je faire pour éviter cela?

Merci!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds to me like a whistle that would happen if you're closing your mouth and moving your tongue forward during the /ɔ̃/, just before the second /k/ sound. It would be your mouth getting into position to make the /y/ sound, but a little too early.

You can verify this theory by doing a pronunciation drill where you repeat the initial syllable /kɔ̃/ many times before saying the rest of the word, e.g. /kɔ̃kɔ̃kɔ̃kɔ̃klyr/ ... sounds a bit impolite so do it where nobody who understands French can hear you :)

If this theory is correct then you should only hear the whistle in the last one of these /ɔ̃/ sounds (or not at all, if the drill fixes it).

EDIT: after you confirmed that this only happens at the last vowel. I'm sorry I don't have any experience with this kind of speech issue to provide tried-and-true remedies. Just a couple things to keep in mind (here I assume, based on your usage of English in the question, that you are a student of French as a second language or "FLE")

- First off it doesn't impede understanding; many people probably won't even notice it. No need to stress out too much about it if your primary goal is to be understood.
- The good news is that you're doing the hardest part correctly: your nasalized consonant /ɔ̃/ is perfect in isolation and so is the /y/. Since many languages don't have either of these vowels you've likely had to learn one or both of them and you're doing fine.

I might still suggest a couple of things:

- Considering that you can say the syllables independently but have trouble when they quickly follow each other, maybe do a drill where you say /kɔ̃/, pause, /ky/, pause, /kɔ̃/, etc. and gradually speed up and shorten the pauses between syllables
- Do an exercise where you first pronounce the word without the initial /kɔ̃/, then with the /kɔ̃/ but a slight pause between the two parts: "currence, con-currence", "clure, con-clure"

Hope this helps!

Comment: Well, your theory is correct in that it just produces the whistling sound at the last syllable. But the problem persists :)

Comment: @Mumfi added some thoughts on how you may be able to fix. Good luck!

Comment: I'm a student of French as a third language, but yeah.. it's not my first language at least :) 
I think you were on to something above your edit where you pointed out that I was moving towards /ky/ too fast. Oddly enough, when I just alternate rapidly between /ky/ and /kɔ̃/, the whislting sound is not produced. So there is some interplay with the /l/ too I guess. 

Anyways, whenever I try to focus on keeping the /ɔ̃/ position right until the next /k/ sound, the sound disappears, though I do slip up sometimes.